# Naming Guidelines for PHP Storm

Tags: php, coding-style, ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am used to have `Resharper` in `Visual Studio` which warns me, if a Methodname, Constant, Field, Property or Variable isn't in the right Case in terms of Microsoft Coding Style.

For PHP I am using PHP Storm as IDE. It is developed by `Jetbrains`, the company, which already developed `Resharper`.

I am search for a similar Option for this. I looked into `Inspections` from the Options and navigate to `PHP`

Many good Features that are in `Resharper` are also here. But not `Naming Guidelines`.

So, is there a Plugin or Some Option I don't see, to get `PHP Storm` warn me, if I write `HelloFRomHEre()` instead of `helloFromHere()`?

Regards

Comment: Look at **CodeSniffer** -- PhpStorm has integration with it.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for your suggestion. Sorry for my late answer. I have taken a deeper look into this. It could be a startig point. But it wouldn't fit my requirements. I would call it "workarround". Sure it works, but it could work and integrate better.

Comment: Of course: EVERYTHING must be done **natively** in PhpStorm. While C# (VS) has no such separate existing tool it does makes sense to have it done in Resharper. But PHP has such tool already -- WHY it needs to be **RE-implemented** in PhpStorm? Of course -- it will be faster and easier to configure it (turn on/off individual inspections) .. but still.

Comment: In any case: do you have any complaints about CodeSniffer integration / suggestions about **re-implementing** of such rules natively in PhpStorm -- welcome to the more appropriate place -- PhpStorm's Issue Tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: @LazyOne, please post your comment as answer. I will accept it, since it seems, current, it is the best way. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LazyOne pointed out, **CodeSniffer** is current the best option. There is no native way implemented in PHPStorm (Also the new 8 release).

PEAR:
http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/redirected

Manual for PHP Storm:
http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/using-php-code-sniffer-tool.html

This is current the only solution, but i am looking forward to a better integration.